# May I know how to report phishing with Gmail API?

Tags: gmail, report, phishing

It is easy to report phishing in Gmail UI, but I want to report a phishing attack with Gmail API. May I know how to do it and what the api endpoint is?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. All Gmail API methods are listed in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest). Marking a message as spam is only available through the web UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the label SPAM to an email using the Gmail API and it will have
the same effect as marking the email as Spam in the UI

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75938799/392335