# How to report a message as spam from the Gmail API?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

It is possible in the GMail UI to report an email as spam. I have not found this feature in the Gmail API documentation. What would be the proper way to do it? Does adding the SPAM label to the email have the same effect?

[image: Report as spam]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question, yes, when you add the label `SPAM` to an email using the Gmail API will have the same effect as marking the email as Spam in the web UI since based on the [Google Documentation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858):

> Tip: When you click Report spam [image: warning] or manually move an
> email into your Spam folder, Google will receive a copy of the email
> and may analyze it to help protect our users from spam and abuse.

Remember that the `folders` in Gmail are basically labels, based on the information in this [documentation](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9260550#:%7E:text=In%20Gmail%2C%20you%20use%20labels,can%20also%20search%20by%20label).

So when you mark an email as SPAM in the web UI, you are essentially adding the label `SPAM` to the email, the same as with the Gmail API.

**Reference:**

- [Method:    users.labels.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/list)
- [Manage    Labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels)
- [Google Workspace Learning    Center](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9260550#:%7E:text=In%20Gmail%2C%20you%20use%20labels,can%20also%20search%20by%20label.)
- [Mark or unmark Spam in    Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858)